Proving completeness of a proof system
I found some material on this post regarding the topic, but I'm failing to implement it.
Here is an example:
The set of connectives in use is $\left \{ \neg ,\rightarrow \right \}$.
The new proof system define as follow:
Axioms: for all $\alpha ,\beta ,\gamma \in WFF_{\left \{ \neg ,\to \right \}}$:
$A_1-A_3$ : HPC axioms
$A_4 : \neg\alpha \to \left ( \alpha \to \beta \right )$
Inference Rules: for all $\alpha ,\beta ,\gamma \in WFF_{\left \{ \neg ,\to \right \}}$:
$M_1:\frac{\alpha }{\alpha \to \alpha }$
$M_2 : \frac{\alpha \to \beta\ , \ \alpha \to \gamma }{\alpha \to \neg\left ( \beta \to \neg\gamma \right )}$
$M_3 : \frac{\alpha \ , \ \alpha \to \neg\left ( \beta \to \neg\gamma \right )}{\beta }$
I have been told that if I can prove HPC axioms and inference rule (which is only MP) from a given proof system, I will be able to say the proof system is complete.
My understanding of "proving inference rule", which in this case is only MP, is to show $\left \{ \alpha \ , \ \alpha \to \beta \right \}\vdash\beta $  from the given proofing system.
I was able to it.
Can I say that the proof system is complete?
(Side note: the new proofing system is sound but I want to tackle the issue of completeness directly)

@MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you. I want to be sure, in order to show that "MP rule is a "derivable" rule"  I need to show that $\left { \alpha \ , \ \alpha \to \beta \right }\vdash\beta$ from the given system , i.e., using only the axioms and the inference rules of the given system ?

As long as you can use the same implication twice in the rule $M2$, you can show $\alpha, \alpha \to \beta \vdash \alpha \to \lnot (\beta \to \lnot \beta)$, which then yields $\alpha, \alpha \to \beta \vdash \beta$ by M3.

The idea is: you have a "standard" proof system - called HPC - with three axioms and one inference rule: Modus Ponens, that we know being complete wrt classical semantics.
And we have a new proof system S, the one above, with some axiom and three different rules of inference.
If so, proving that system S can derive HPC axioms (obvious) and that Modus Ponens rule is a derivable rule is enough to conclude that the new system can prove all that HPC is able to prove, and thus that the system S is complete.
